# Toro ready start lawn mower dead

Tags: lawn-mower, engine

Toro Personal Pace Recycler 22 in.
Variable Speed Self-Propelled Gas Lawn Mower
Briggs & Stratton Engine
Model #: 104M02-0010-F1
Serial:1412305830813
Parts List: [PDF](http://bsintek.basco.com/BriggsDocumentDisplay/29jnzEO.RFzXFix2.pdf)

Last worked one month ago.
Now, I pull and pull, but engine won't start (doesn't even sound like it tries)

This [youtube video](https://youtu.be/NU_ClhSoaQM?t=172) @ 2:53 is how my lawn mower sounds and acts. Later on the guy sprays some stuff into the engine and shows how it will start and cut off. My lawn mower won't even do that.

TL;DR: Aside from checking/changing the spark plug, is there anything else I can do or should I just figure out how to load the thing in my car and have it serviced?

Troubleshooting steps I've done:

- Drained the oil and put new SAE 30 in.
- Drained the fuel and put new fuel in (fresh from gas station).
- Watched a youtube video saying use 13/16 inch spark plug
- Looked up accessories for mower on Home Depot and was recommended [13/16 spark plug](http://www.homedepot.com/p/Champion-13-16-in-RJ19LM-Spark-Plug-for-4-Cycle-Engines-868-1/202323892?quantity=1&str_nbr=0585)
- **Purchased** the spark plug and a 13/16 spark plug socket
- Tried to remove the spark plug with purchased socket and the socket was too damn big
- Much shakes fist, very frustration
- Plugged the spark plug wire back into spark plug and tried to start
- Pulled a few times and back at square one

More troubleshooting with DIY users help:

- I've verified blue spark by unscrewing the spark plug from the engine, stuck it back into the "lead" (the cable that was plugged into the spark plug), and pulled a few times.

I can turn it in for warranty but its heavy and I'd prefer to know how to fix this instead of having to lug it back to Home Depot and wait who knows how long for them to fix it. Next thing I'm going to do is see if I can at least get the socket right so I can check the spark plug. Local Home Depot does not sell the spark plug itself, gotta order it.

EDIT: while I was at home depot to get a new socket and some cleaner, the dude told me i needed to look at the spark plug in order to see which one it is. Turns out its an AUTOLITE 3924 in case anyone else needs to get one. Alts are the `Champion 5/8in RC12YC` and the `E3.20`

Comment: Unplug the spark plug lead, attach your new spark plug, and have someone have a good look at it while you pull the starter. If they can't see a spark, it's upstream from there and you should refer to [BillOer's Answer](http://diy.stackexchange.com/a/72867/2509). Otherwise, the issue is more likely in fuel delivery or a clogged air filter, but in my experience it's generally spark that's the issue.

Comment: You can also hold the plugged in spark plug by the business end while pulling the starter. You *should* receive a pretty good jolt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We need to divide the problem in half. In the case of an engine we need to decide if it's not starting because of gas or spark. Too test the engine for spark your going to need an extra set of hands or some electrical tools. If you have help you can have some one hold the spark plug wire close to the spark plug while you pull the string. If electricity is getting to the spark plug you will see a spark jump from the wire too the sparkplug. IF you see a spark we can now trouble shoot the fuel.

The easiest way to check the fuel would be to buy a can of ether, that is what the guy in the video sprayed into the engine. If it runs for a couple seconds (or even acts like its about to start) then we know the problem is with the carburetor or fuel system in general.

If you complete these next steps please come back and +1 my answer(so I get a notification) and I will continue to assist you in trouble shooting. Regardless if it's spark on fuel the trouble shooting only get more and more complex from here. I would replace the spark plug and if that doesn't work I would look at calling Home Depot, they might even pick the lawn mover up for you. They are good people.

How to check for spark video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mUOmsGiirTU

Comment: for checking the fuel, do i just spray into any hole I can find, or do I have to figure out how to open up the engine compartment/carburetor and spray it there? Or do you mean pour it into the fuel compartment/oil compartment?

Comment: Your going to want to spray it into the air intake or at least into the air filter.

Comment: These two videos may help https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=upaWRxC-ydU

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=T6RFYLzmGkU

Comment: lol "I don't do crack". Uh huh.. :D

Comment: Great vids, they helped a lot. I'll try it in about 18 hours when i get off work and then see how things go.

Comment: Also, just to try, pull the air cleaner out when trying to start it.  Engines need fuel, spark, and air.

Comment: So I got some carburetor cleaner and sprayed it into the hole where the air filter is. Nothing. Also tried to clean the spark plug by spraying carburetor cleaner on it, and then leaving it to try for an hour before re installing and trying again, still nothing. There did seem to be some kind of whirring noise after one of the pulls, but that's about it.

Comment: I'm not going to have anyone over until Friday to check for a spark. In the meantime I'm going to buy a new sparkplug and see if it helps at all.

Comment: @ton.yeung - Unscrew the plug and lay it on the metal engine housing to make contact (anyone holding it, is likely to get a nasty surprise even through the insulation). With it still plugged in, turn off the lights, pull the cord and check for spark.

Comment: Do you mean put the lead on the metal housing (the cable that connects to the spark plug)? I'm confused because I'm reading this as 1. unscrew spark plug and put on housing, 2. with "something" still plugged in, lights off, start the mower to see any sparks. The last part other than that "something" I understand, and its brilliant. The steps leading to it, i do not understand.

Comment: This should clarify it https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mUOmsGiirTU

Comment: @ton.yeung - The *something* is the spark plug. You'll have to unplug the wire to unscrew it (if you use a socket) -then plug the wire back in to test it (while its threads are making contact -not the *point* of the plug). See the video at 2 minutes in.

Comment: @Mazura, Levi, this is great, i got blue spark, so it saves me a trip to home depot to buy a new plug. Looks like its fuel.

Comment: @ton.yeung You will need to insert the spark plug, pull the string 15-20 times with the choke off, and take the spark plug off, the spark plug should be moist and you should smell gas inside the combustion chamber (where the spark plug unscrews from). If you have gas it cold still be to little or 2 much, but if you dont have gas we can start looking at the carburetor

Comment: I can confirm that there is gas on the spark plug.

Comment: @ton.yeung Hmm, this is a tough one, Could be spark but not proper spark, Could be timing but that is normally not an issue. Could be a problem with the valves. Could be too much gas or not enough (carb or choke problem). Could be lots of things at this point. We never did narrow it down. We actually made the scope bigger by not finding a single point of failure, and the gas is newer gas right? This thing didn't sit all summer and then you fired it up? Gas does go bad. So at this point I would recommend you take it in to be serviced as it only gets much more complex from here on out.

Comment: Yes, went to gas station to get new gas can and new gas. Drained out the old gas completely before adding new gas in. Also replaced the spark plug with the E3.20 brand since its supposed to give better sparks. I have an old lawn mower I inherited before it crapped out, and this has been an interesting experience. I think I'll try to make that one work again by taking it apart :D This one though, I'll put in a claim against the warranty, like you suggested. It's only been two months since I got the lawn mower, so I'd rather get it fixed for sure by some professionals.

Comment: @ton.yeung yeah, just repeat these steps for your old one to narrow down the problem.

Answer (score 1):

If it's anything like my Toro 22' Recycler, you'll have to take the top off and replace the igniter. There's a flywheel with a small (possibly neodymium) magnet attached to it. The magnet passes through a coil and generates current. In my case, that coil was bad. To come to that conclusion I first tested for fuel delivery, and after confirming that fuel was getting to the engine, I concluded there must not be a spark. It's been running fine since then. I could not find the igniter online and had to get it from a local lawn tool repair outlet.
Edit: I used a piece of card stock as a gauge between the magnet and the coil plates. It gave me a clearance of 0.008". I could not find out what the clearance was actually supposed to be, but 0.008 seems to have worked just fine.
Edit: Here's what the igniter (ignition module) and flywheel look like:
[image: Toro Ignition Module]
[image: Toro Flywheel]

These are for the Tecumseh engine, so I don't know how they would translate, if at all, to the Briggs & Stratton engine.

Comment: @BillOer- Is the magneto the same as an igniter? They now sell electronic starters that replace the condensers under the flywheels.  You can upgrade  and installs easily. No moving parts,  it sends 3 x as many spark impulses than the condenser, only 2 wires to connect and their cheap.

Comment: @ojait are you saying if its the igniter, instead of replacing it, I can get an electronic starter instead? Or is a magneto just an upgrade to the stock starter?

Comment: @ton .yeung- yes. the electronic ignition takes the place of the old condenser and points. It's a super upgrade to any small combustion engine that don't use a battery. It fires a spark faster and more often so the engine starts easier. I installed one in an ancient Kioritz weed wacker and it started. Check this link for purchase:  http://www.amazon.com/Oregon-Replacement-IGNITION-UNIVERSAL-33-053/dp/B0009XFXTQ/ref=sr_1_21?s=lawn-garden&ie=UTF8&qid=1441204936&sr=1-21&keywords=lawn+mower+electronics

Comment: @ojait, my Toro mower is about ten years old. I use the term "igniter" rather than magneto, because I'm only referring to the coil part of the whole magneto. In my mower, there is a permanent magnet attached to the flywheel. This magnet passes through the igniter (or coil) and generates a spark for the spark plug.

Comment: @BillOer- Understood. What are your thoughts concerning an electronic component as a replacement to the points and condenser on small engines? Nothing to calibrate, no moving parts to maintain, easier starts... You would think this one solid state ignition item would be the holy grail of combustion engines, but manufacturers still use points and condensers on present models! makes you go "hmm".

Comment: @ojait, I agree points and condenser are a bit...antiquated. My Toro is ten years old and as far as I can tell, the magnet and coil generates the spark. The high voltage wire to the spark plug comes straight off the ignition module. And FWIW, it seems the original failed because it was mounted too close to the flywheel and got whacked each time the magnet came around. I remember hearing a "clicking" sound as it ran. The coil is a U-shaped affair and probably generates two sparks on each fire.

Comment: @BillOer- Yeah I guess after awhile of working on engines we develop an intuition for an engine that is about to fail. Maybe subconsciously ,like when a piston is going bad or a carburetor isn't dialed in right  we hear a sound different from what we know is correct.

Comment: @ton.yeung- The second photo of the flywheel is where you'll find the points and condenser (under the flywheel). That is the location for the solid state ignition module.

Comment: @ojait, in my mower the ignition module sits on the side of the flywheel. The open U faces the flywheel.

Answer (score 1):

OK, I had the same problem with my Toro and my mechanically inclined BIL took off the air filter opened up the carburetor poured fuel directly into it and it started.  I am not sure if this is how it was meant to be done, but I know it works.  He also told me to start it once or twice during the winter.  In Texas we have short winters so it won't be that bad.