# Generator issues

Tags: generator

I tried started my generator.  It started, but smoked & backfired, & then would go off.  I let the gas run out & filled with fresh gas.  Now it won't start.  Any help is appreciated the blizzard is coming!

Comment: What model/manufacturer is this generator?

Comment: When was the last time you used it, and if it was a significant time ago, did you drain the gas before putting it away?

Comment: It's a Generac 7500.  I used it recently (end of Fall) & there was very little gas left.  I cleaned the air filter after posting this & it started, but again, backfired & kept shutting off.

Answer (score 3):

Disassemble and clean the carburetor. You may need a new diaphragm. But having emptied it of gas, it may no longer be primed: spray starting fluid into the carburetor. Also, check the fuel line and its filter for blockage.

That's all I got. You could try asking at [mechanics.stackexchange.com](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/); the car guys there probably know engines better.

Edit: I forgot step one. [Check the plug for spark](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/72860/toro-ready-start-lawn-mower-dead/72861#72861).

Comment: "Questions related to the maintenance and repair of motor vehicles and their accessories, internal combustion engines, **even in applications other than automotive so long as the question is related to engine or engine accessories**." –MV.SE

Answer (score 2):

It is notoriously difficult to make a diagnosis of a poorly or non-running internal combustion engine without having your hands, ears, and eyes on it. I would recommend that you either take it to a professional mechanic, or, if you have a mechanically savvy friend - call them for help!

Comment: Agreed. I don't think we ever needed the model number (but diagnosing one over the phone is tough); it's a combustion engine and unlikely to have fuel injection, but if it does, OP prob be better off getting a pro's help.